# Chef 'application_wlp' cookbook throws Load Error

Tags: websphere, chef-infra, websphere-liberty

I am trying to set up a virtual machine running a Liberty profile server with a sample application deployed following the instructions given in this link : https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/getting-started-chef-cookbooks-liberty-profile/

But instead of using vagrant, I use an EC2 instance as a virtual machine. I get the following error when I ssh and run "sudo chef-client" in the virtual machine.

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.5.1
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["apt", "starter::JSPExamples"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - starter (1.0.0)
  - apt (2.9.2)
  - application (5.0.0)
  - poise-service (1.0.2)
  - application_wlp (0.2.0)
  - wlp (0.3.0)
  - java (1.36.0)
  - poise (2.4.0)
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2015-11-12T10:20:23+00:00] WARN: Chef::Mixin::LanguageIncludeRecipe is    deprecated, use Chef::DSL::IncludeRecipe instead.

[2015-11-12T10:20:23+00:00] WARN: Called from:     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/application_wlp/providers/wlp_application.rb:20:in `class_from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:42:in `class_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:42:in `class_from_file'

=======================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/application_wlp/resources/wlp_application.rb
=======================================================================

LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- ApplicationCookbook
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: You're following a fairly old example with the very newest Chef versions, but I can't find the file referenced in your error message on version 0.2.0 of the application_wlp cookbook: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.chef.wlp/tree/0.2.0/resources.

Comment: Yes, Even I couldn't find such a file.. So had a doubt if something was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The application cookbook recently released a new major version (5.0.0) which is not backwards compatible with the earlier releases. The tutorial you are following is out of date and needs to be updated. In the short term you can probably fix your issue by explicitly downloading the last 4.x version of the application cookbook from https://supermarket.chef.io/.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/WASdev/ci.chef.wlp.application/issues/3 over on the cookbook to make this more obvious.